# Altering x-axis for dates in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set that has dates for many years. I can easily filter the data by month or week, but I was hoping to change the X axis to make it start in October and end in April.

Is there a way to do this in Tableau without altering the original data and listed dates?

Comment: Does right clicking the axis, clicking Edit Axis, and setting the range work?

Comment: For some reason -- maybe my damn Mac -- that wasn't working for me. Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about it ending in April since that would not be a full 12 months but you can make it start in October. Right click on your date field > Default Properties > Fiscal Year Start. Then select October.